# Swift: URL(fileURLWithPath:) returns no value at all, not even nil

Tags: swift

I am getting a weird result where `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` returns no value when called in a certain way. I've included code below (a simple macOS command line tool) to illustrate the problem.

I am using Xcode 10.3, on macOS 10.14.6. It also happens on iOS 12.4.1.

To see the problem, run the code below. Place a breakpoint on the `return` statement in the `weirdStuff(withURL:)` function, and on the 2nd-to-last line. Run the app, and when the code breaks on the `return` line, hover the pointer over the 4 `let`s in the function to examine their values. Here's what's weird:

1. `badURL` will not show any value at all! And the "Variables View" pane of the debug console will show that the value has not been defined.
2. `copyOfBadURL` will contain the correct value from `badURL` even though apparently `badURL` doesn't exist!

The conclusion is that `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` is failing (eg, `badURL`) when the `fileURLWithPath:` parameter value is a variable, but succeeds (`goodURL`) when the parameter value is a constant string. That can't be right!

Next, continue running the app so that you get the to other breakpoint. If you hover the pointer over `url2` you'll see that the correct value was returned via `return badURL`. You can also see that `badURLNowGood` has a value as expected, even though this is essentially the same call that failed when called within my testing function.

What's going on here? I've never seen a variable never even be defined (after execution) before (ie, `badURL`).

```
import Foundation

func weirdStuff(withURL urlParam: URL) -> URL {

    let pathFromParam = urlParam.path
    let badURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathFromParam)
    let goodURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Dir1/file.txt")
    let copyOfBadURL = badURL

    print("func: badURL = \(badURL)")       // is valid here but not if you hover above
    print("func: copyOfBadURL = \(copyOfBadURL)")
    print("func: goodURL = \(goodURL)")

    return badURL   // Breakpoint on this line; hover over 4 values above

}

// Call function with URL weirdness
let url1 = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Dir1/file.txt", isDirectory: true)
let url2 = weirdStuff(withURL: url1)
print("main: weirdStuff(withURL:) result = \(url2)")

// Now do similar calls outside of the function
let pathFromURL1 = url1.path
var badURLNowGood = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathFromURL1)
let goodURLUsingString = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Dir1/file.txt")
print("main: badURLNowGood = \(badURLNowGood)")     // Breakpoint here
print("main: goodURLUsingString = \(goodURLUsingString)")
```

Comment: So the only issue is that the debugger isn't showing the proper value? It sounds like the code is working fine otherwise, correct?

Comment: No... it caused other problems in my actual code as the value percolated throughout the code. It was fairly involved and took quite a bit of effort to trim it down to this example code, so I definitely want to get it fixed rather than just avoid the problem in the debugger. For example, in my original code I was assigning the value to a variable called `result`, and then I return it via `return result`. The value that the calling function was getting back was the string: `"result"` (ie, the name of the variable!).

Comment: The code is working correct (swift 5.0.1) and prints in every case `file:///Dir1/file.txt`. So what exactly do you expect?  And maybe you should also show the `"result"` case, I cannot believe this...

Comment: It's not correct, IMHO. In the first breakpoint, type `po badURL` into the debug console and see the error output. (I assume this is just the same root problem.) I'd like the code to work and be debuggable. Is this the symptom of something else that will cause an unexpected problem in the future, in some cases? As for `"result"` yeah I wouldn't have believed it if I hadn't seen it myself. I'm not sure if I'll invest the time to trim down another sample of my code where that happened, since it wouldn't really change anything, it seems.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not at all sure that this is only a problem with the debugger that I can safely ignore. It seems just as likely that it's a problem with the core language/libraries, and the debugger is just reflecting the problem.